# Clarification on what to do if I am seeking feedback on a solution

Tags: support, allowed-questions, asking-questions, policy

I am currently studying a couple of disciplines on my own through reading. Have a couple of queries regarding he usage of this site..

$Q_1$: What is the site policy on posting solutions to exercises found in standard textbooks and looking for feedback on it. As in if I am unsure about certain chosen exercises is it alright if I post my solution and ask if it is correct enough?

$Q_2$: Say I have just finished completing an exercise which is actually a question that has already been answered on the site. If my solution is different to all of the answers to that particular post or if all the answers to that particular post are too sophisticated for my level should I post a new question or should I post it as an answer to the above mentioned (already answered) question which is pretty much on the same problem?

Looking for some clarification. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A1: We have a [proof-verification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-verification) tag for questions of this type, so go ahead.
For such questions, it is usually good to stay around after asking, as people may well have additions and/or questions to it fairly quickly, and in case there was just some small detail that needed fixing (or some small misunderstanding that needed clearing up), then it would be a shame for that to take a long time.

A2: If you think you have a completely different solution, but you are unsure if it is correct, you can post it as a new question (again using the above mentioned tag), making sure to mention the other question and why this is not a duplicate (as you are asking about whether a specific solution is correct).
If it is correct, then you can add that solution as an answer on the other question and have your own question closed as a duplicate (possibly with a note edited into the question that you have added such an answer to the other one).

Comment: Thanks for the tip.. Should I use the (proof-verification) tag or the (solution-verification) tag? And what is the difference, if you don't mind?

Comment: Ahh, I had forgotten we had both. I would say it depends on how the problem has been formulated. If the solution is only a proof, then  probably the first one. Otherwise, the second one might be more appropriate.

Comment: Right. Thanks loads. Much appreciated.